# LINQ no delayed loading

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there an easy way to force linq to execute a join on a foreign key relationship without accessing an arbitrary member of the referenced table?

For example, if I have a Company object that references a `TaxBracket` table and there is a relationship and linq association set up between them I want to be able to access `Company.TaxBracket` after the data context has been disposed and without having to do `var temp = Company.TaxBracket.randomMemberVariableToExecuteQuery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataLoadOptions.LoadWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx). So, you'd say something like

```
using(var context = new MyDataContext()) {
    DataLoadOptions dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<Company>(c => c.TaxBracket);
    context.LoadOptions = dataLoadOptions;

    // some query
}
```

Comment: Its `context.LoadOptions` not `context.DataLoadOptions`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx)

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Company>(c => c.TaxBracket);
using(var context = new DBContext(){LoadOptions = options})
{
    //...
}
```